# Check if mouse is ABOVE an element jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, position, element, offset

I want to check if the mouse is currently within the visible area of a div.
I know I could use the following code:

```
$("#div").is(":hover");
```

In jQuery.

However, there may be another div partially over my `#div`, so the hover will not work for my case.

I need to check if the mouse is above an element, regardless of any elements that are on top of it (preventing the hover check).

Comment: If "element B" that is partially obscuring your "element A", and is not a descendant of "element A", you'll have to programmatically check the position of "element A" against the mouse position.

Comment: I was rather trying to avoid that. But if it's really the only way, i'll have to do it that way. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Goodluck! (PS, probably good to catch this event at `body` level, or at the level of the closest ancestor to both "element A" and "element B" - if the calculation becomes too much for the browser, then think about throttling it)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need any actions to be applied to the element above the div in question you can simply apply pointer-events:none to it. This should solve your problem and you should be able to use $('#div').hover() perfectly fine.

Test Example.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
        div {
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            position:absolute;
        }
        div#one {
            top:0;
            background:orange;
        }
        div#two {
            top:20px;
            background:blue;
            opacity:1;
            pointer-events:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('div#one').click(function(){
            alert('one-clicked');
        });
        $('div#one').hover(function(){
            console.log('one is being hovered!')
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

All the best,
Shalom